# Standard rational functions from matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, multilinear-algebra, rational-functions

In linear algebra we get introduced to standard polynomials that are associated to matrices such as characteristic polynomials and determinants.

What are some of the standard rational functions that can be associated to matrices?

Comment: What's really the point of this question? Any motivation? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is a standard way to associate an algebraic curve to a linear pencil of matrices: to a one dimensional family $A+Bt$ we associate
$$\det(A+Bt-\lambda I)=0.$$
When $B$ has image of dimension $1$, this is of first degree in $t$; solving with
respect to $t$ we obtain a rational function associated to the pair $A,B$.

EDIT. But of course this is not the only way. As another example, you can consider $2\times (d+1)$ matrices of rank at least $1$, and associate to them rational
functions of degree $d$ by using the entries in the natural order as coefficients of
the numerator and denominator. Some of these functions will be reducible, and have
smaller degree. This correspondence leads to a useful geometric interpretation
of the Grassmannian $G(2,d+1)$, see, for example,  MR1931599, MR1888795, MR2196025,
MR1917479.

Comment: do you mean rank(B)=1?

Comment: @Turbo: Yes, this is what I mean.